# react native how to upgrade project version 0.61.0to latest version

Tags: react-native

**React native 61 to 64 +**
current version 0.61.0

```
upgrade to latest version 
best way to upgrade project
```

Answer (score 1):

> npx react-native upgrade cd ios  pod install

**for upgrade to specific version You may specify a React Native version by passing an argument, e.g. to upgrade to 0.64.0**

npx react-native upgrade 0.64.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not simply change the version and `npm install` again. You may view the official documentation for help.

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/